# Is there a way to get innerText of an element as if a user copied its contents?

Tags: javascript

Page probably somehow modifies text that copied to the clipboard, so copied text comes with emojis, but InnerText contains plain text. Is there a way to trigger copy event and get it value with JS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Comment: [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) - Also, depends on what you mean exactly by *"comes with emojis"*

Comment: *Is there a way to trigger copy event and get it value with JS?* - no because you can add whatever you want through clipboard api and different part of code can add different things. This is not bound directly to `copy` event

Comment: @mew4au7 why exactly do you need this